# Dfference Between Two running total query

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, dax

I have written two types of Running total with dates as below:-

```
30 days running Total Sales =
CALCULATE (
    [Total Sales],
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Dates ),
        Dates[Date] > MAX ( Dates[Date] ) - 30
            && Dates[Date] <= MAX ( Dates[Date] )
    )
)
```

and

```
Running Total =
CALCULATE (
    [Total Sales],
    DATESINPERIOD ( Dates[Date], LASTDATE ( Dates[Date] ), 30, DAY )
)
```

I am trying to Calculate 30days running total of Total sales. But both of the queries give the different result as Below.

Can anybody explain ......

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The values `MAX ( Dates[Date] )` and `LASTDATE ( Dates[Date] )` should be the same here.

The difference is that your first measure is subtracting 30 days whereas the second is adding 30 days.

Try using `-30` instead of `30` in the second one.

Comment: Thanks, Alexis, It worked ... So computationally which one should be used

Comment: I'd expect them to be about the same. Use whichever you think will be more readable to yourself or others in the future.

Comment: Thanks, A lot Bro